# What is the distribution of a mixture of exponential distributions whose rate parameters follow a gamma distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution, mixture-distribution, exponential-distribution, compound-distributions

I want to know the theoretical distribution of a mixture of exponential distributions whose rate parameters are distributed according to a gamma distribution:

$$ y\sim\text{Exp}(\theta), \quad\text{where}\quad \theta\sim\Gamma(r, \beta).$$

Specifically, I am looking at $r=4$ and $\beta=2$.

Comment: The question appears clear enough to me: given $r$ and $\beta$, let $\theta$ follow a gamma distribution with parameters $r$ and $\beta$ (whether these are scale or rate params doesn't matter for now), denoted $\theta\sim\Gamma(r, \beta)$. Next, $y$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\theta$, denoted $y\sim\text{Exp}(\theta)$. That is, we have a [compound distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution), AKA a mixture. Q: What is the unconditional distribution of $y$ with parameters $r$ and $\beta$?

Comment: At least that is what the original question seems to have asked, and I have tried to clarify this specific question with my edit and answer it. I will vote to reopen. Can someone clarify to me where this question is unclear?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Well, $\theta$ wasn't defined; it _could_ be the mean rather than the rate. The variable $n$ & its role were also unexplained.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: true. But converting between a mean and a rate formulation for the exponential is not overly hard. I assumed $n$ referred to a sample size and removed it in my edit.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: (1) The compound distribution would be something else if it were the means distributed according to a gamma distribution. (2) Quite possibly, but why mention it then? I think your edits do a fine job of clarification, but I can see why the q. was closed in its original version.

Answer (score 5):

For all $y \ge 0$ the value of the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) of $Y$ is

$$S_Y(y\mid\theta) = \Pr(Y \gt y\mid \theta) = \exp(-y\theta)$$

and, taking $\beta$ to be a *rate* parameter for the [Gamma distribution,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) the probability density function of $\theta$ is proportional to

$$f_\theta(t) \propto t^{r-1}\exp(-\beta t).$$

Consequently the survival function of the [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) is

$$S(y) \propto \int_0^\infty S_Y(y\mid t) f_\theta(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty t^{r-1}\exp(-(\beta+y)t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Substituting $u = (\beta+y) t$ gives, with no calculation,

$$S(y) \propto \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{u}{\beta+y}\right)^{r-1}\exp(-u)\,\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{u}{\beta+y}\right) = (\beta+y)^{-r}\int_0^\infty u^{r-1}\exp(-u)\,\mathrm{d}u$$

which is proportional to $(\beta+y)^{-r}.$

The [axiom of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom) asserts $S(0)=1$ from which we obtain the implicit constant, giving

$$S(y) = \beta^r\,(\beta+y)^{-r} = \left(1 + \frac{y}{\beta}\right)^{-r},$$

thereby exhibiting $\beta$ as a [*scale* parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter) for this mixture variable.

This is a particular kind of [Beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution), sometimes termed a [Lomax distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) (up to scale).

If $\beta$ is intended to be a scale parameter for the Gamma distribution rather than a rate parameter, replace $\beta$ everywhere by $1/\beta$ and, at the end, interpret it as a rate parameter for the mixture variable.

---

This distribution tends to be [positively skewed,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) so it's better to view the distribution of $\log Y.$  Here are the empirical (black) and theoretical (red) distributions for a simulation of $10^4$ independent realizations of $Y$ (where $r=4$ and $\beta=2$ as in the question):

[image: Figure showing ECDF and histogram]

The agreement is perfect.

The `R` code that generated this figure illustrates how to code the survival function (`S`), the density function (its derivative `f`), and how to simulate from this compound distribution by first producing realizations of $\theta$ and then, for each of them, generating a realization of $Y$ conditional on $\theta.$

```R
S <- function(y, r, beta) 1 / (1 + y/beta)^r            # Survival
f <- function(y, r, beta) r * beta^r / (beta + y)^(r+1) # Density
#
# Specify the parameters and simulation size.
#
beta <- 2
r <- 4
n.sim <- 1e4
#
# The simulation.
#
theta <- rgamma(n.sim, r, rate=beta)
y <- rgamma(n.sim, 1, theta)
#
# The plots.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(ecdf(log(y)), xlab=expression(log(y)), ylab="Probability", 
                   main=expression(1-S[Y](y)))
curve(1 - S(exp(y), r, beta), xname="y", add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)

hist(log(y), freq=FALSE, breaks=30, col="#f0f0f0", xlab=expression(log(y)))
curve(f(exp(y), r, beta) * exp(y), xname="y", add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution), under the "Examples" section, informs us that:

> Compounding an exponential distribution with its rate parameter distributed according to a gamma distribution yields a [Lomax distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) [9].

The reference [9] is to Johnson, N. L.; Kotz, S.; Balakrishnan, N. (1994). "20 Pareto distributions". *Continuous univariate distributions*. 1 (2nd ed.). New York: Wiley. p. 573

Comment: Yuh, but is that really the question?