# How can I verify that my solution is correct when finding the PDF and CDF of a random process?

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes

If I have $X(t) = \sin(\omega t + \theta)$ where $\omega$ is constant and $\theta$ ~ $U[0,2\pi]$, and I need to find the PDF and CDF of $X(t)$, then how can I confirm my solutions for the PDF and CDF are valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the usual mathematical techniques of checking your derivation, checking for consistency (*e.g.,* differentiating the CDF to see whether it equals the PDF), and considering whether your answer makes sense, whenever there is a question of determining the distribution of a random variable (or collection of variables) you almost always have available the option of **simulation.**

In many cases this is a mechanical, nearly mindless exercise -- and it is carried out using such different reasoning processes (it's a programming exercise rather than a mathematical one) that it serves as an excellent check.

For this purpose it's a good idea not to be clever or efficient about the simulation: make the code reflect the information you have as closely as possible.  In the example below, the process $X$ is computed as

```
X <- outer(theta, times, function(theta, t) sin(omega*t + theta))
```

That's simple to code and easy to compare to your formula.  The rest of the code is just pre- and post-processing.

**You can find thousands of worked examples here on Cross Validated:** search for names of common uniform random number generators, such as [`runif`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=runif+simulat*) and [`rnorm`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rnorm+simulat*), made popular on the `R` platform.

**As an example,** below is `R` code to simulate your process for eight randomly-chosen times $t$ and display histograms of the simulated values.  Over those histograms are plotted the graphs of the PDF I think is the solution.  You can see these graphs agree closely with the histograms, thereby bolstering the likelihood I am right.  (You can perform a distributional goodness of fit test of each graph for a more rigorous check, but that's a matter for a separate thread.)  If you wish to check the CDF, plot the empirical cumulative distribution functions (available through the `ecdf` function in `R`) and overplot those with your CDF to compare.  See, *inter alia*, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/471775/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/472768/919, or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/464101/919 for examples.

[image: Figure]

The code is below.  Because you are not asking for the answer, I have omitted the body of the PDF function `f`.  Nevertheless, this figure already reveals a lot: the distribution of $X(t)$ does not vary with $t.$

```R
#
# Specify the process by initializing its parameters.
#
omega <- 4/3
#
# Select a set of "times" at which to sample it.
#
times <- sort(runif(8, 0, 2*pi/omega))
#
# Sample the process `n` times, storing each independent sample in a row of `X`.
#
n <- 1e5
theta <- runif(n, 0, 2*pi)
X <- outer(theta, times, function(theta, t) sin(omega*t + theta))
#
# Plot histograms of each X(t).
#
h <- function(x, t) {
  hist(x, xlim=c(-1,1), freq=FALSE, breaks=50, col="#f8f8f8", border="#505050", 
       xlab=expression(X[t]), cex.lab=1.25,
       main=paste0("t=",signif(t,3)), cex.main=1)
  f <- function(x) # (Body omitted.)
  curve(f(x), add=TRUE, n=201, lwd=2, col="Red")
}
par(mfrow=c(2,4))
invisible(sapply(seq_along(times), function(i) h(X[,i], times[i])))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: That was a very thoughtful response. Thank you for spending the time to introduce this capability to me